# Topologizing of sets.

Tags: general-topology

The following is a theorem from James Dugundji's Topology.

**Theorem:** Given any family $\Sigma=\{A_\alpha|\alpha\in\mathcal{A}\}$ of subsets of $X$, there always exists a unique, smallest topology $\tau(\Sigma)\supset\Sigma$. The family $\tau(\Sigma)$ can be described as follows:

It consists of $\emptyset, X,$ all finite intersections of the $A_\alpha,$ and all arbitrary unions of these finite intersections. $\Sigma$ is called a subbasis for $\tau(\Sigma),$ and $\tau(\Sigma)$ is said to be generated by $\Sigma.$

In his proof he has forced $\tau(\Sigma)$ to be the intersection of all topologies containing $\Sigma.$ Now my questions are,

*1) why is it the intersection of all such topologies?,
2) what is the crux of this theorem?*

Comment: This is a common construction in mathematics.  I can briefly motivate why you might want to work through the details.  If there is a "smallest topology" $\mathcal{T}_\Sigma$ containing $\Sigma$, then it is one of those in the family you are intersecting.  By taking their intersection we will get $\mathcal{T}_\Sigma$ back again (because "smallest" means all of these topologies contain $\mathcal{T}_\Sigma$, which is itself one of those topologies).

Comment: The "crux" is to show the intersection of a family of topologies on $X$ is indeed a topology on $X$.  I'll get you started:  every topology for $X$ has $X$ itself as an element (the open set $X$), so the intersection of these topologies is nonempty.  Continue and show all parts of the definition are satisfied.

Comment: I think I got it. But is it true that $\Sigma$ is a subbasis for $\tau(\Sigma)$ because $\tau(\Sigma)$ is forced to be the way it is?

Comment: For many authors the above construction *defines* what "subbasis" means.  See the Wikipedia article on Subbasis for a discussion of this definition and alternatives used by some authors.